# How do I use CSS Opacity to when I hover over an Image multiple images become light

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a website that has multiple images on. what i want is when i hover over one of the images all the others become lighter with opacity. I would be very grateful if someone could help me out with this as i have been Googleing for quite a while now and i cant seem to find the answer im looking for. thanks

Comment: if you added code we can give you a better/ more accurate answer

Comment: At least show your html and what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```
$('.myImg').hover(function(){
   //On hover IN, change the opacity
   $(".myImg").not(this).stop().animate({ "opacity": 0.3 });
}, function(){
   //On hover OUT, reset opacity to default
   $(".myImg").not(this).stop().animate({ "opacity": 1 });
});
```

First of all, you need to give all your images a common class. Next, with jquery i would have a Hover Event. Inside the function, you tell jquery to target all images with the common class, except the one the cursor is currently hovering ".not(this)". This will change the opacity of all images, except the current one.

Comment: `jQuery` answer to a `CSS` question... maybe this would work, but is not what OP is after.

Comment: @gmo why -1 and how come it is CSS question?

Comment: What about the title.. `How do I use CSS Opacity...` also, there's no `jQuery` tag in OP question. Different would be if the answer start with: *If you can use jQuery, then this might help*... for example. (making it optional)

Comment: @gmo, fair enough :), but its tagged with javascript, and it cannot be done with css only

Comment: Well, we don't know, the question is really poor in detail to assume something (or anything really)

Comment: In all fairness, this is impossible to accomplish without JS, so this answer is a valid one.

Comment: @gmo I have to agree with you, question isn't clear enough... what I wanted to say I wouldn't give -1 for that answer because (according to poor description) it does what it should, but its just my personal opinion ;)

Comment: @amaro, agree... It does what it should, but that's not the main question.. If you want, the right answer then would be ***you can't without...*** Otherwise I could give a working answer for example with `mootools`.. and must be valid too? No, OP ask for a `CSS solution`... any way, it's also my opinion only.

Answer (score 0):

Well you didn't give any sample code, so here's a CSS-only method. You would need to place your images inside of a parent container and give it a class such as "parent".

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <img src="bla.jpg" />
    <img src="bla.jpg" />
    <img src="bla.jpg" />
    <img src="bla.jpg" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent:hover > img{
    opacity:0.5;
}

.parent > img:hover{
    opacity:1;
}
```

This will cause all your images' opacity to change when you hover over their parent element, but will keep the opacity of the image you're hovering over the same.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9VF9w/)

Comment: The problem with this, is all the images will fade out when the mouse enters the parent, even if its not above an image.

Comment: yes that's the only limitation, i.e. if the parent element has padding. It would be easier to accomplish with the use of javascript/jQuery, but he asked for a CSS opacity fix, and this is the best I can come up with at the moment.

Comment: Yup. Unfortunately CSS does not support a previous sibling selector. You can almost make it work with `img:hover ~ img { opacity: .5 }` but this only affects the images following the hovered one.